# How to fix problem with margin when using twoside?

Tags: double-sided

I am using `twoside` so that I can alternate between headers, but this causes the left margin to be bigger than the right on even pages and vice versa odd pages, as you can see below.

[image]

This is my code.

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{remreset}{The remreset package}

\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textit{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\textit{Monzur Rahman}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\textit{Page \thepage}}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\textit{Monzur Rahman}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\textit{Page \thepage}}


\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\gdef\leftmark{\thesection\quad#1}\gdef\rightmark{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\gdef\rightmark{\thesubsection\quad#1}}

\section{Lorem}
\subsection{Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is quite normal: the outer margin is always larger than the inner margin since when you open a book, you see *two* inner margins side by side.

Comment: Ah okay. I have another question. How can I stop the page number being printed in the footer?

Comment: You explicitly add the page number to the footer!?

Comment: Do you want to place the page numbers in the header?

Comment: It's automatically printed in the centre, but I want to remove that and print it as in my code

Comment: @Johannes_B What's wrong with that?

Comment: Ask a new question with a mwe.

Comment: @Johannes_B I just want to know why you're so surprised that I add the page numbers to the footer. Is there something wrong with that?